# pandas.value_counts for NA

Tags: python, pandas, types

[`pandas.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)
works for numeric arrays with `None`:

```
> s = pd.Series([1,2,1,None])
> vc = s.value_counts(dropna=False)
> vc
 1.0    2
 2.0    1
NaN     1
dtype: int64
> vc.index
Float64Index([1.0, 2.0, nan], dtype='float64')
> vc[1], vc[float('NaN')]
2 1
```

but not for strings:

```
> s = pd.Series(['1','2','1',None])
> vc = s.value_counts(dropna=False)
> vc
1      2
2      1
NaN    1
dtype: int64
> vc.index
Index([u'1', u'2', nan], dtype='object')
> [type(o) for o in vc.index]
[<type 'str'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'float'>]
```

How come there is a `float` here?!

```
> vc['1']
2
> vc[float('NaN')]
TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [nan] of <type 'float'>
```

How do I access counts for the `None` in `s`?

Comment: I don't know why the same does not work when the index is of type object but `vc.loc[np.nan]` works for both.

Comment: it looks like there is a limitation with indexing when the `Index` is of mixed type, in the first case the index is promoted to `FloatIndex` but in the second it has `dtype` of `object` and is of mixed type with `NaN` values, so if the type is numeric or datetime then the Index type gets promoted to `FloatIndex` or `DatetimeIndex` which do support `NaN` values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also surprised to see that `cv[np.nan]` does not work, but this does: `vc.loc[np.nan]`

Comment: Is this a bug? Should I report it?